# Retrieve original argument name from args

Tags: python

How in this case I can print the original argument name?

```
def test_if_null(*args: Any) -> None:   
    for argument in args:
        if not argument:
           print(original_argument_name)
q='t'
w=None
e='e'
    
test_if_null(q,w,e)
```

expect to be printed 'w'

Answer (score 1):

You can use **kwargs

```py
def test_if_null(**kwargs: Any) -> None:   
    for name, arg in kwargs.items():
        if not arg:
           print(name)
q='t'
w=None
e='e'
    
test_if_null(q=q,w=w,e=e) # Prints w
```

In this case kwargs is a dictionary of all the names of arguments and values passed: `{'q': 't', 'w': None, 'e': 'e'}`

Comment: Alternatively, if you wanted to use *args, maybe try using the `globals()` function to get all defined variables

Comment: I know.
test_if_null(some_very_long_long_name_that_has_a_meaning=some_very_long_long_name_that_has_a_meaning)